# testing a workflow service

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

I have writen a workflow service but when I run it in the WCF test client I just get a message  **ONE WAY MESSAGE has been sucessfully sent to the service side**.

I tried to put some breakpoints in the XAMLX service but it didn't help. No breakpoint was hit. I tried to put a breakpoint in the actions I defined, but that was also not hit. What am I mistaking here?
Should I expect the debugger to work? Why does it say a ONE WAY OPPERTION?

Answer (score 0):

A WorkflowService generates a one way contract if you have a Receive activity with no correlated SendReply activity.

You can debug a WorkflowService with a one way message - I tested it just now to be sure and it worked for me.  If the debugger is not working for you then

Look for a message in the Debug output window like

```
Instrumentation for debugger fails.  
Reason: Could not find file 'c:\DeclarativeServiceLibrary2\Service1.xamlx'.
```

If you see this it is because the path to the XAMLX file inside the file itself is incorrect.  For example see this XAML

```
<p1:Sequence DisplayName="Sequential Service" 
sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="c:\DeclarativeServiceLibrary2\Service1.xamlx"
```

You can manually edit the path or if you open the workflow in the designer and make any change and save it, the path will be updated.